# Bitwise operation on a dynamic data structure

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, information-retrieval, adjacency-matrix, boolean-search

I am implementing a simple document indexer for information retrieval. Now I need to implement an incidence matrix, that should be able to be extended dynamically (not satisfied with just a static array or smth).

And to make boolean search possible I have to be able to perform bitwise operations on the rows of the matrix. However, I have not come up with a fast solution. The question is data structure for each row of the matrix.

If it were just a `std::vector<bool>`, is it possible to do FAST bitwise operations on it? Or is there any other data structure, like `BitArray` from C#, applicable in the situation?

Comment: The `std::bitset` 'container' may be what you're looking for ... but I think we need more information, here.

Comment: How would I apply `std::bitset` to `std::vector<bool>`? Or how would I dynamically my incidence matrix? What way to store it? Bitset is not a dynamic container, so it surely cannot represent a row of a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `FAST` is your goal, look into using largest `int` available on your system (likely - `uint64_t`) and do a simple bitwise operations on that. If your matrix is wider that 64 - use an `std::array` of those. Then check if your compiler generates SIMD instructions from your code. If not - consider using intrinsics https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#

Comment: But how do you suggest dynamic extending of `std::array` or `uint64_t`? The main goal is to avoid any kind of conversion to static things like you suggested and perform bitwise operations on dynamic containers, like C#-`BitArray`. The main goal is a C++ `BitArray` if that already exists.

Comment: Obviously, if you don't know the width of your matrix - `std::array` won't work. Use `std::vector`. If you need other features of C#'s `BitArray` - you would need to implement it yourself.